# Is there a list of Apple TV 4th gen screen saver images?

Tags: appletv

How can I find out where the pictures on the Apple TV 4th gen screen saver are coming from? Some of them I recognize, but I'm stymied by a few and I'd love to know their source.

Comment: Which screensaver are you using? There are a few of them...

Comment: Whatever the default is? I didn't know there were others!

Comment: Is it the time lapse of different cities?

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth generation Apple TV screen saver is composed of QuickTime movie files. You can see the JSON file that Apple TV loads them from at the following URL.

http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/000/Features/atv/AutumnResources/videos/entries.json

There are versions of the screen saver for Mac and Windows, not developed by Apple, which you can download at the below links.

https://github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial/releases/

https://github.com/cDima/Aerial/releases/

Answer (score 1):

At this moment there are the following locations:

- Abu Dhabi (1 Day shots)
- Dubai (4 Day shots and 2 Night shots)
- Great Wall of China (3 Day shots)
- Greenland (2 Day shots and 1 Night shots)
- Hawaii (6 Day shots and 2 Night shots)
- Hong Kong (3 Day shots and 1 Night shot)
- London (2 Day shots and Night 3 shots)
- Los Angeles (3 Day shots and 1 Night shots)
- New York (3 Day shots and Night 3 shots)
- San Francisco (6 Day shots and Night 6 shots)